# How to pass arguments in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

I am running my docker image in my local machine (executing my performance test based on the arguments provided) with the following command
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYGgL.png)

whereas, satheeshpandianj/my-perf-app is my image name and rest (QA Commerce ListMarkets 1 5 Volvo) are arguments passed to this image to run. I have already pushed this image to docker hub. I want to run this docker image in kubernetes. I wrote the deployment yaml file like below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
   app: perf
  name: perf
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: perf
  template:
   metadata:
     labels:
      app: perf
   spec:
     containers:
       image: docker.io/satheeshpandianj/my-perf-app
       name: perf
       args: ["QA", "Commerce", ListMarkets", 1, 5, "Volvo"]
```

When I am executing "kubectl apply -f perf.yaml", I am getting a below
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyWKa.png)

Can someone help me to resolve this error? Or please correct me what changes need to be made in my yaml file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you have to define also the `command` - see the k8s docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: @ddegasperi - Can you please let me know what to pass in command? command: ["What command to pass here"]

Comment: It should be the command that is also defined in the Dockerfile either as CMD or ENTRYPOINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the spec.containers, expects a list.
You have to update your yaml to this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
   app: perf
  name: perf
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: perf
  template:
   metadata:
     labels:
      app: perf
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: docker.io/satheeshpandianj/my-perf-app
       name: perf
       args: ["QA", "Commerce", ListMarkets", 1, 5, "Volvo"]
```

Yes, only the `-` is missing